# How to extract value from hashed output

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to make updates to a standard voting dapp. My aim is to list out voter who has voted for a candidate.
So far I have implemented the following:

voting.sol:

```
struct voter {
    bytes32 votedFor;
    bool hasVoted;
}

mapping (bytes32 => uint8) public votesReceived;
// Mapping for persons who have already voted
mapping (bytes32 => voter) public voters;   
function lookUpVoter(bytes32 hashedVoter) view public returns (bytes32){
  bytes32 candidateDetails = voters[hashedVoter].votedFor;
  return candidateDetails;
}
```

index.js:

```
function lookUpVoter(){
    voterName = $("#voter-info").val();
    var vals = contractInstance.lookUpVoter.call(voterName);
    $("#votes-cast").html(vals);

}
```

The output i am receiving from index.js is hashvalue "0x4b6576696e204200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000".
I need the candidate name instead. 
Please help me identifying what I am missing from the code.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is not a hash, it is a `bytes32`.

You just need to call the `toAscii` function from Web3.js:

```
var str = "0x4b6576696e204200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

web3.toAscii(str.slice(0,18))
```

> "Kevin B"

Note we only need the first 16 characters of the hexadecimal for 32 bytes, which means 18 characters total if you include `0x`, hence the use of the `slice()` function.

See documentation [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii).

Or for Web3.js 1.0, use `web3.utils.hexToAscii` as documented [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii).

Comment: take a look at the update where I use the slice function to get rid of unnecessary characters :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a hashvalue, that's the string you're looking, it's just hex encoded. If you just plug the hex string into the function `web3.toAscii`, it'll return the ascii version of it.

Comment: I will be changing my code in index.js :

Comment: function lookUpVoter(){
    voterName = $("#voter-info").val();
    var vals = contractInstance.lookUpVoter.call(voterName);
    var out = web3.utils.toAscii(vals);
    $("#votes-cast").html(out);
} --- is this correct? I am new to solidity so I am unware of the usage. Please help!!